# begin(), end() annoyance in STL algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I like STL algorithms, and prefer use algorithms rather than usual loops.
Almost all STL algorithms are usually used as:

```
std::algorithm_name( container.begin(), container.end(), ..... )
```

`container.begin(), container.end()` - is one of most popular words pair in my projects.

Does anybody have the same problem?
How do you Guys solve this problem?
What could you propose to avoid this duplication?  I see a few ways for solution, but all of them have different limitations (macro usage, not compatible with usual pointers, etc.).

Comment: Nothing special. It won't hurt if you accept it as a fact of life.

Comment: Yeah, I can. It will be easier for me but also it will be step to degradation=) Maybe my point is very idealistic..

Comment: This question could really have used a better title.

Comment: I also thought for a time I would like to be able to do std::algorithm_name( container, ..... )
however then all the containers would have to implement begin/end exactly the same to get the iterators and the algorithms would no longer be minimal.

Comment: Just a comment, since it is likely not advice you can follow:  change to a language that you can extend yourself, instead of having to wait for the language designers.

Answer (score 29):

The next C++ standard, C++0X (where X stands for, hopefully, 9) will add the possibility to change from iterator perspective to container perspective. You will be able to do eg.

> std::sort(my_vec);

If you cant wait for this I would recommend you to look at: [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/range/index.html)

And if you are a really interested in iterators/ranges I would recommend you to read Andrei's "*[iterators must go](http://www.boostcon.com/site-media/var/sphene/sphwiki/attachment/2009/05/08/iterators-must-go.pdf)*"

Comment: So, what do we do with this answer now?

Comment: Did `std::sort(my_vec)` really make it into the C++11 standard? According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort, it seems like `std::sort` still requires iterators.

Comment: It's still a TS but documented here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges/algorithm/sort

Answer (score 19):

Many have encountered this nuisance.  Though the iterator concept is exceptionally general, it lacks some usability.

Enter the 'range' concept.  It is to be preferred to avoid *any* code duplication.  So if you encounter .begin() and .end() pairs all over the code, it's good practice to create a layer in between the 'iterator-getting' and the actual algorithms.

References:

- [RangeLib](http://rangelib.synesis.com.au/)
- [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/oven.aspx)

...

Comment: +1. There's also Boost.Range: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/range/index.html

Comment: Nice. Thank you, @xtofl, @j_random_hacker. I didn't see this libs, earlier.

Answer (score 7):

```
#define ALL(x) (x).begin(), (x).end()

sort(ALL(vec));
```

Comment: 'cos macros which evaluate their parameters multiple times are always entertaining ;-)

Comment: macros should be **deprecated and shot** in C++11!! :p

Answer (score 3):

[C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Range-based_for_loop) has addressed this minor annoyance within the language.

Comment: I use not just for_each algorithm. But anyway, thank you, it will helpfull.

Answer (score 3):

First, I don't think it's a big issue. In general, I don't really care about typing a few more characters. readability is more important, and I think begin/end is perfectly readable.

Shorter container names can help though (con.begin() is easier to type than container.begin())

And passing iterators around instead of the container itself means that you don't have to call begin/end more than once in any case.

It's not really something that bothers me.

Comment: I don't care about typing additional symbols in variable/function/class/.. name, but I'm trying to avoid duplications.

Comment: Why? What's the difference? Typing a class name twice is just as much duplication as typing begin() twice, isn't it?

Comment: Long names improving readability, but in case with begin()/end() we have code duplication. Why I should pass container.begin(), container.end() if I want apply algorithm for all contained items?

Comment: Jalf, you are not against typing begin and end but recommend shortened variable names, right?

Comment: I'm not for or against anything. :p
And long names can be a pain to read. They definitely do not always improve readability. I'm simply pointing out I don't think it's a big problem in either case. But there are small simple tricks you can use to shorten it a bit without hurting readability. :)

Comment: It's quite annoying when you want to pass a temporary. It means that you have to store the temporary as a local first to be able to use both begin() and end() on it when passed. If there was just one input it could have been passed directly. Compare `A a; alg(a.begin(), a.end(), a);` vs `alg(A())`.

Answer (score 3):

If it got *really bad*, I would probably create a bunch of templates for my most commonly used algorithms in a new namespace:

```
namespace my_ranged_algorithms {
    // Metafunction for extracting an appropriate iterator from
    // the container type
    template <typename T>
    struct get_iterator_type_for;

    // For vectors
    template <typename T>
    struct get_iterator_type_for<std::vector<T> > {
        typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator type;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct get_iterator_type_for<std::vector<T> const> {
        typedef typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator type;
    };

    // For C arrays
    template <typename T, size_t N>
    struct get_iterator_type_for<T(&)[N]> {
        typedef T* type;
    };

    // Generic begin() and end() wrappers

    // For all standard containers        
    template <typename Cont>
    typename get_iterator_type_for<Cont>::type begin(Cont& c) {
        return c.begin();
    }

    template <typename Cont>
    typename get_iterator_type_for<Cont>::type end(Cont& c) {
        return c.end();
    }

    // For C arrays
    template <typename T, size_t N>
    typename get_iterator_type_for<T (&)[N]>::type begin(T (&c)[N]) {
        return c;
    }

    template <typename T, size_t N>
    typename get_iterator_type_for<T (&)[N]>::type end(T (&c)[N]) {
        return c + N;
    }

    // Finally, the actual algorithm wrappers

    // copy
    template <typename Cont, typename OutIter>
    OutIter copy(Cont& from, OutIter to) {
        return std::copy(begin(from), end(from), to);
    }

    // remove
    template <typename Cont, typename T>
    typename get_iterator_type_for<Cont>::type remove(Cont& from, T x) {
        return std::remove(begin(from), end(from), x);
    }

    // etc.
};
```

Then call them like so:

```
vector<int> a, b;
using namespace my_ranged_algorithms;

copy(a, back_inserter(b));
b.erase(remove(b, 42), b.end()); // Remember to call erase() after remove()!
```

Answer (score 3):

[This nice presentation](http://www.boostcon.com/site-media/var/sphene/sphwiki/attachment/2009/05/08/iterators-must-go.pdf) [PDF] about a possible future solution to this was recently linked from reddit. it discusses how to fully replace iterators with the range concept.

Comment: Thanks, nice article. I was filling all about what Andrei write in this presentation, but couldn't organize my minds and formulate all what I want. Range concept is very good direction.

Answer (score 1):

boost::range_ex will solve this before c++0x.

And it's not hard to write a few wrappers yourself in the meantime.